# Тип "(get: any) => { [k: string]: () => void; }" не может быть назначен для типа "Record<string, () => void>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, типы, преобразование-типов

Я выполняю следующие преобразования:
`sourceArray: {string: SomeObject}` -> `[string, SomeObject][]` -> `[string, () => void][]` -> `{string: () => void}` примерно следующим образом:

```
// Из кода убраны лишние детали для облегчения понимания
let something: Record<string, () => void> = 
Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(sourceArray)
    .filter(([name, someObject]) => true)
    .map(([name, someObject]) => [someObject.name, () => openModal(someObject.data)]
  )
```

Однако когда я присваиваю результат полю типа `Record<string, () => void>` он мне пишет ошибку:

`Тип "(get: any) => { [k: string]: () => void; }" не может быть назначен для типа "Record<string, () => void>".`

`В типе "(get: any) => { [k: string]: () => void; }" отсутствует сигнатура индекса для типа "string".`

Почему я не могу преобразовать `{ [k: string]: () => void; }` в `Record<string, () => void>`, и как мне сделать это?

Comment: пример из вопроса работает без ошибок. Попробуй сделать пример в playground  чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть ошибку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается я допустил глупейшую ошибку: я хотел что бы свойство являлось get-методом, и я случайно сделал так, что создаётся не get свойство, а возвращается метод, который принимает аргумент get